# How to send mail to a group using java?

Tags: java, email

I want to send mail to a particular group of users rather than individual email addressess? Or is there any way around to get the individual users from a list and send mail to each of them.

Regards

Comment: Please paste your code, what have you achieved so far and where is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS(Java Message Service) which there are Sender and Receiver. And, one sender can send to multiple receivers at same time.

Answer (score 0):

**this method we can use use**

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendEmail {

    public  void SendingEmail(String Email, String Body) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "test.myemail@.com"; // Your mail id
        String pass = "PASSWORD"; // Your Password
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
            }
        });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("senanayakaamesh@gmail.com"));// ur email
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(Email));// u will send to Email
            message.setSubject("Use this code as Sequrity code ");
            message.setText(Body);
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            System.out.println("sending");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SendingEmail("to email", "Massage");
            System.out.println("sucess ending");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```